# How to use RewriteCond in following case

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am making API. I am green about .htaccess, but I am making API. And I'd like to make this link:

```
https://example.com/api/v1/exampleField/1234/orders
```

Into something like that:

```
https://example.com/api/v1/api.php?input=exampleField/1234/orders
```

I was looking in the internet, but haven't found anything. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: _“I was looking in the internet, but haven't found anything.”_ - you must be kidding, right? URL rewriting is a very well documented, and already broadly discussed topic. Sorry, but this just sounds like you did not actually bother to make any serious effort.

Answer (score 0):

In your /api/v1/ folder create .htaccess file

Then put this into that file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)$ api.php?input=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled and htaccess files allowed in your Apache configuration.
And as far I remember last line in .htaccess file should be empty

Comment: I did this, that's how is looking mine .htaccess file right now:
```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)$ api.php?input=$1 [QSA,L]
```
(last line is empty). And when I go: https://example.com/api/v1/example/input/123, it just returns error 404.

Answer (score -1):

Create .htaccess File in your api/v1/ folder

```
Options -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?input=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

And try to make your api.php using Rest api

```
require_once("Rest.inc.php");
class API extends REST {

    public $data = "";
    const demo_version = false;

    private $db     = NULL;
    private $mysqli = NULL;
    public function __construct() {
        // Init parent contructor
        parent::__construct();
        // Initiate Database connection
        $this->dbConnect();
        //error_reporting(E_ALL);
        error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    }

    /*
     *  Connect to Database
    */
    private function dbConnect() {
        require_once ("../connsqli.php");
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
        $this->mysqli->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    }

    /*
     * Dynmically call the method based on the query string
     */
    public function processApi() {
        $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['x'])));
        if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0)
            $this->$func();
        else
            $this->response('Ooops, no method found!',404); // If the method not exist with in this class "Page not found".
    }

public function exampleField($id,$code) {
  // Your function code
}

private function json($data) {
        if(is_array($data)) {
            return json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
        }
    }

    /* String mysqli_real_escape_string */
    private function real_escape($s) {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->mysqli, $s);
    }
}

// Initiate Library
$api = new API;
$api->processApi();
}
```

Rest.inc.php

```
class REST {
    
    public $_allow = array();
    public $_content_type = "application/json";
    public $_request = array();
    public $_header = array();
    private $_method = "";      
    private $_code = 200;
    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->inputs();
    }
    
    public function get_referer(){
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }
    
    public function response($data,$status){
        $this->_code = ($status)?$status:200;
        $this->set_headers();
        echo $data;
        exit;
    }

    private function get_status_message(){
        $status = array(
                    200 => 'OK',
                    201 => 'Created',  
                    204 => 'No Content',  
                    404 => 'Not Found',  
                    406 => 'Not Acceptable',
                    401 => 'Unauthorized');
        return ($status[$this->_code])?$status[$this->_code]:$status[500];
    }
    
    public function get_request_method(){
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }
    
    private function inputs(){
        $this->_header = $this->get_request_header();

        switch($this->get_request_method()){
            case "POST":
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_POST);
                break;
            case "GET":
            case "DELETE":
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_GET);
                break;
            case "PUT":
                parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$this->_request);
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($this->_request);
                break;
            default:
                $this->response('',406);
                break;
        }
    }       
    
    private function cleanInputs($data){
        $clean_input = array();
        if(is_array($data)){
            foreach($data as $k => $v){
                $clean_input[$k] = $this->cleanInputs($v);
            }
        }else{
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
                $data = trim(stripslashes($data));
            }
            $data = strip_tags($data);
            $clean_input = trim($data);
        }
        return $clean_input;
    }       
    
    private function get_request_header(){
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($key, 'HTTP_') === 0) {
                $headers[str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower(substr($key, 5)))))] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $headers;
    }
    
    private function set_headers(){
        header("HTTP/1.1 ".$this->_code." ".$this->get_status_message());
        header("Content-Type:".$this->_content_type);
    }
}
```